How do I create a PDF that contains a hash that the PDF also resolves to?
I have a PDF document from an e-signing service where the SHA256 code inside the document also is the same hash the entire document resolves to, when I test it with a SHA256 checker.
How can this be achieved programmatically? It's good if it can be solved with NodeJS, but I can go with another language/environment if it's too demanding with NodeJS.
Also, if there is any libs out there, it would be the preferred approach.
I googled like a nut, but I can't find any.

that would have to be left out of the hash calculation.  (There are certain things like file meta-data that are not used to compute hash... so there can be a placeholder var in the file that is only a reference to certain meta-data var name...)

that should not be possible, please provide proof of concept :-)

@Progman how could that other question (which mostly links to another question) resolve this problem? As far as I see, signing the PDF itself is not the main problem, but showing the hash within the PDF document itself

what e-signing service, what sha256 checker?
